# How to type text inside a TableViewCell and move to the next TableViewCell to Continue typing text in Swift

Tags: swift, textfield, uitableview

when the tableview comes open I want to enter text in the field and then press done to move to the next cell for more text input

Answer (score 1):

1. Conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.
2. Implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` method.
3. Call `.becomeFirstResponder` on the next textField. Remember to return true.

Comment: This assumes the `UITableViewCell`s already contain `UITextField`s, which isn't clear from the question.

Comment: By process of elimination and the fact he added the tag "textfield", I presumed this is what he meant.